# Cannot boot from external DVD

Tags: windows, startup

I have changed my internal DVD with Crucial m4 SSD and I have put the DVD in to an external case.

I'm trying to update the SSD firmware and install Mavericks but I can't boot anything except MAC OS installation DVD.

I have tried to

- boot the official Crucial update DVD: it hangs
- install Windows 7: it hangs
- install Windows 7 on bootcamp: it hangs on windows boot
- install windows XP: it doesn't boot
- boot Hirens 15.1: it boots Mini Windows XP, but I cannot start DOS programs

Also, I have reset the SMC and NVRAM, no success.

Any Ideas why I cannot boot anything else than MAC OS? What is wrong: the DVD drive, the EFI or something else?

Comment: You say it hangs, but how long did you wait for installation before terminate ?

I had a similar problem: the installation was stopped saying 1 second before proceed (seemed to be hanged). I had to wait for half an hour and finally, the installation process rebooted and continued.

Comment: Then I see the "press any key to boot from DVD ..." I press any key and it hangs .. I was waiting for it for 5 minutes and no progress ..
When I try to boot the Crucial update CD when the linux kernel starts loading  it freezes after several loading dots (Loading vmlinuz.gz ..........)

Comment: Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: Did you check your DVD ? Did you try to make a bootable USB drive ? Are you SSD and other drives without errors ? Which model do you have ? Is it compatible with Mavericks ?